# C - runtime error, `malloc(sizeof(int))` causing program to crash

Tags: c

Here is a piece of code:

```
int* linenump;
// ... other stuff
printf("----\n");
linenump = malloc(sizeof(int));
printf("*****\n");
```

The program only print out `----` then stopped, pop up a window says that the program has stopped, I paste the code in VS then build&run it, no errors, the program works fine.

It's a console application.

So, what I want to know is, in what situation that this will happen? and **how should I solve it?**

Thanks in advance.

---

EDIT:
here is the full source code: <del>urldown</del>

Comment: Any stacktrace?  Your snippet looks pretty OK to me.  I'm also assuming that you're developing on a standard desktop setup and not on some obscure platform with a custom libc.

Comment: This code is fine as long as // ... other stuff doesn't try to access lineump which is not initialized. Can you show more of the program.

Comment: @user814064 https://github.com/0xdeadbabe/indexer/blob/master/src/indexer.c#L282

Comment: I bet you $100 that if you unit tested your code, your error would pop out at you. Writing unit tests feels unnatural, but writing more code actually saves you time. Test your assumptions.

Comment: @towry, nothing really jumps out.  As Paul says, try using valgrind.

Comment: This should be buflen += BUFLEN // this is wrong: buflen += BUFLEN-1;

Comment: This is one byte/character to little space malloced because strlen doesn't included the terminating \0 chracter: wordstr->word = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(word));

Comment: Hey @user814064 if you add this as an answer, I'll upvote you! Thanks for helping him.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You probably have some heap corruption somewhere earlier in the program but this is not showing up until this point. Run your code under [valgrind](http://sourceforge.net/p/valgrind4win/wiki/Home/) to identify the real problem.

Comment: Well, I use the `drmemory` tool and I have solved this problem, thank you! and thanks to @user814064, thanks for pointing out where the error is!